# Get script to wait for file dialogue to return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page where I want to prompt the user for a file to upload, but I don't want to display the `<input type="file"/>` element.

I have a button that triggers the file dialogue to display, but the code doesn't wait for the dialogue to return.

Is there an event I can hook into that is raised when the file dialogue returns? Is there some other thing I've not thought of?

This is what I have at the moment, it uses an alert to block the code. I want something less hacky.

```
function importValues(e)
{
    var f = document.getElementById('file');
    f.click();
    alert('loading'); //hack to make the code wait for the user to choose a file before making the ajax call
    var formdata = new FormData(jQuery('#frmImport')[0]);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'importFile',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        chache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    });
}
```

Comment: a `change` event on the file `<input>` element ?

Comment: @wroniasty - good thinking, I'll give it a try

Comment: @sagivo a file dialogue, to choose a file.

Comment: @wroniasty: yep that worked!  If you want to write out an answer I'll give you some rep!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i think you need to refactor your code and handle native file upload events.
if you have some element like file dialog

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

then you can hook up to its [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and specially to `onchange`

```
$(function(){
    $("#file").change(function(e){ alert('selected') });
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Vt9/)

Comment: Thanks, that's just what wroniasty suggested in the comments :)

Comment: yea, no point in me writing the same answer just to get rep, so just mark this one @MattEllen